# Software for escrow agency

Tags: gratis, open-source, git

I need software that could be used for an escrow agent (E).

```
Company X is Buying software from Company Y and wants E to be a middle man.
```

Since there shall be multiple versions of the software my original idea is to have GIT service on secured in house server in escrow company (E), however, company E wants specific escrow service software,

and I cannot find anything.
Any recommendation is welcome.

Comment: Welcome aboard. Why the [tag:git] tag? Also, ***must*** it be [tag:open-source], or would [tag:gratis] be acceptable? (the latter is likely to get more answers). Which operating system should it run on, or do you want something web-based?

Comment: @Mawg Git tag as git based software would be accepted. Open-source prefered, gratis is mandatory. Thank you for answer

Comment: Just my opinion, but I could be wrong. I have used version control for a few decades now, but not git. Seeing the [tag:git] tag would make me think that I can't help and, if I am in a hurry, I might not look at the question. Similarly, I might think that I know a [tag:gratis] solution, but not [tag:open-source]. Personally, I only use "must have" tags and add "nice to have" in the question, in the hope of drawing people in. Others may think otherwise; perhaps it's worth a question on [Meta](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/)?